# proper javascript for a while loop

Tags: javascript, mootools

I would like to know proper code to add another condition to the while loop code below. Specifically where **.id !='k2-label'** I would like **.id (!= 'k2-label' && !=some-label)** (*this is the PHP version of what I want to accomplish*), except I don't know javascript. The change is to be added to the following code:

```
while (next.getFirst().getNext().getFirst().id != 'k2-label') {
                        joomla_bits['titles'].push(next.getFirst().getFirst());
                        joomla_bits['items'].push(next.getFirst().getNext().getChildren());
                        next = next.getNext();
                    }
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just say `next.getFirst().getNext().getFirst().id != 'k2-label' && next.getFirst().getNext().getFirst().id != 'some-label'`, but that causes the `getFirst().getNext().getFirst().id` to be executed multiple times.  You should add an intermediate variable:

```
var id = next.getFirst().getNext().getFirst().id;
while (id != 'k2-label' && id != 'some-label') {
    joomla_bits['titles'].push(next.getFirst().getFirst());
    joomla_bits['items'].push(next.getFirst().getNext().getChildren());
    next = next.getNext();
    id = next.getFirst().getNext().getFirst().id;
}
```